# How to run C++ console program (which is a standalone C++ file not a console application project in Code::Blocks) in ConEmu?

Tags: conemu, terminal-emulator, code-blocks

I am able to change the default terminal of all the console applications in Window 7 to ConEmu using [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/959337/454831) and it was really great. Until now I was creating a C++ console application **project** in Code::Blocks and when I "compile and run" the project it opens a ConEmu terminal. But when I tried to run a single standalone C++ file (not creating a project) in Code::Blocks it opens a default Windows terminal, not the ConEmu terminal as in earlier case.

How can I change the **default terminal to ConEmu** even if I run a single file C++ program in Code::Blocks?

Some related details are:
(1). I am using Code::Blocks 13.12, (2). I am using Windows 7, (3). I am using ConEmuSetup.151115.exe setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeBlocks ignores requirements for lpCommandLine parameter, described in [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) function. It runs command line containing spaces without quotes. I consider this is a bug of CodeBlocks and it have to be reported to their authors. For information, it runs the following:

```
C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe "C:\source\contest.exe"
```

To run CodeBlocks "using short names", execute `dir /X` from cmd.exe in the root of `C:` drive and look for short name of `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. Most probably, you have to run CB as following `C:\Progra~1\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe`.

ConEmu [build 151122](https://conemu.github.io/blog/2015/11/22/Build-151122.html) introduces a workaround for this CB bug. But, it would be better to report problem to CB authors!

Comment: Ok. In the link mentioned in question, you said that this can be corrected by: Reinstall C:B in the folder without spaces, or run C:B using short names. What do you mean by "**run C:B using short names**" and exactly how can I do that?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/261/